# Smooth scrolling effect using CSS or Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have seen many websites using smooth scrolling ([click here](https://zhenyary.com/) to see an example). So, my question is that how they achieve this effect, do they use some libraries, etc. I have searched for this but didn't find the right answer.

Comment: in your question try to add the code you tried, or what you have done to achieve this that will help others to help you.

Answer (score 1):

you can try using https://github.com/ivmello/easeScroll this jquery this will help you for smooth scrolling on mousewheel, but for other appering animation you have to use some animation library like [gsap](https://greensock.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The effect you are looking for is called Parallax. Do a search for "multi layer parallax websites". There was a good how-to with code high up the first page.

Edit: The second part of the example website is the Hero image (the banners) zooming, you can get that searching "Hero image zooming"